# Azure API Management - Named Values

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Is there a way to have the Named Values record a combination of Text and Expression. Sample format what am trying to achieve is given below, unfortunately I tried all the ways but the expression isn't getting evaluated. Any help is greatly appreciated

[image: Named Values Sample]

Evaluated to:
[image: Trace log]

Comment: Hi Ravi, please refer to the solution I provided below. If it helps you, could you please mark my answer as "accepted", thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using single line of expression, which is not evaluating correctly in this case. Instead, use a multi line expression which will work as expected.
Code snippet for what you are trying: `@{ string str1= "This is date : " ; string str2 = (DateTime.Now.ToString()); return str1+str2 ; }`

The named value propery will look as below;[image]
Output scrrenshot: [image]